# C++ Replace Value in Config File

Tags: c++, qt, replace, text-editor

I am trying to replace a value in a configuration file. It can be edited in a text editor.

> [MODEL]
>       ...
>
> ```
> Latitude = 1.034
> Longitude = 110.58334
>
> ...
> ```

How can I search for the keyword "Latitude" and replace "1.034" with another value? (e.g. 1.04)

Edit: Thanks for the down votes. I have attached my code below:

```
QFile fileReadModels(CP1);
fileReadModels.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream inModels(&fileReadModels);

while(!inModels.atEnd())
{
    QString lineModels = inModels.readLine();
    if(lineModels.isNull())
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        strListInModels.append(lineModels);
    }
}

fileReadModels.close();

int startFlag   = 0;
int stopFlag    = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= strListInModels.count(); i++)
{
    if(strListInModels[i].contains("Latitude", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 1)
    {
        //! get start position
        startFlag   = i - 1;
        //! get stop position
        stopFlag    = i + 2;

        break;
    }
}

//! get data from start till start position
for(int x = 0; x <= startFlag; x++)
{
    strListOutModels << strListInModels[x];
}

//! insert in Ownship1 lat/lon
QString os1LatStr = "    Latitude = " + os1Lat;
QString os1LonStr = "    Longitude = " + os1Lon;

strListOutModels << os1LatStr;
strListOutModels << os1LonStr;

//! get data from stop postion till end
for(int y = stopFlag; y < strListInModels.count(); y++)
{
    strListOutModels << strListInModels[y];
}

//! write to file
QFile fileWriteModels(CP1);
fileWriteModels.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate);
QTextStream outModels(&fileWriteModels);

QString qStrModels = strListOutModels.join("\r");
outModels << qStrModels;

fileWriteModels.close();
```

Comment: You need to make some attempt at writing the code yourself before asking for help. Once you have some code to post with specific questions, you'll be able to get help.

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code here

Comment: I have a long piece of code that does the replacing. What it does is reading in this file line by line into a buffer, then it does 2 parts: (1) loops through the whole chunk and searches for the keyword "Latitude", and determines the startPosition to be x-1. (2) and it determines the endPosition to be x+2. It skips the lines of Latitude and Longitude. Thereafter, I write the contents into the file, from start to startPosition, write in the 2 new lines, then write in from endPosition to end of file. It's not very neat and clean.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I have added my piece of code.

Comment: I suggest looking into `QString::splitRef` with space as separator and using `QString::SkipEmptyParts` to get an array of tokens. Then you can more easily parse it and not worry about extra spaces messing it up.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Thanks for the help.

Comment: do you need to preserve the spacing as well?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror A printout of readLine() shows the *whole chunk* of texts instead of just line by line. I suspect it has something to do with "\r\n" of the file that was read in. Any help on this? I presume it needs to be opened in binary mode, therefore I used QTextStream and QIODevice::Text. If I can read in line by line, then I can perform QString::splitRef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QSettings feature

**location.ini**

```
[MODEL] 
Latitude = 1.034
Longitude = 110.58334
```

You can use QSetting to modify your data

```
//Access your datafile
 QSettings settings("location.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

//Read Data
 QString sLatitude = settings.value("MODEL/Latitude").toString();

//Write Data
settings.setValue("MODEL/Latitude", "18.55");
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful and I have been using it all the while. However, I am unable to change the format of the file I'm going to read in. So it's kinda inconvenient.